# width depending on responsive classes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I **could** use media queries to specify a certain width for the different display styles (xs,sm,md,lg) but then I would have to repeat the widths that are part of the bootstrap media queries

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  img {
    width: 20%;
  }
}
```

Question is: Can I maybe do this more DRY - without repeating the numbers?
My first thought was:

```
img.visible-xs {
  width: 20%;
}
```

But apparently that class does not apply.

Any idea how to do this without using another set of media queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with `less`/`sass` mixins. E.g. with `less` just define

```
@screen-xs: ~"only screen and (max-width: 767px)";
@screen-sm: ~"only screen and (min-width: 767px) and (max-width: 991px)";
@screen-md: ~"only screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px)";
@screen-lg: ~"only screen and (min-width: 1200px)";
```

and then you can use it like this

```
img {
  @media @screen-xs {
    width: 20%;
  }
}
```